# How does describe() in mocha work here?

Tags: mocha, chai

I got this snippet from: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts

[image: Smart Contract Test]

In this test, what does `const { expect } = require("chai")` mean? Also, I thought `describe()` is from the Mocha framework but I don't see any `const { describe } = require("mocha")` and `const { it } = require("mocha")` or something similar along that line here, but this test still runs successfully, why?